# Finding the position of a sting in a sentence [start and end of a sting]

Tags: python

I'm a having a problem finding the positions of strings in a sentence in python. I keep getting the error: unbalanced parenthesis.

```
>>>sent="Of these the Murids (seekers or strugglers,) are formed"
>>>stringlist=sent.split()

>>>[[(m.start(0), m.end(0)) for m in re.finditer(s, sent)]for s in stringlist]
```

output:

```
raise error, v # invalid expression
       error: unbalanced parenthesis
```

It works without the string; (seekers or strugglers,); output:`[[(0, 2)], [(3, 8)], [(3, 6), (9, 12)], [(13, 19)], [(45, 48)], [(49, 55)]]`

My question is how do I find the starts and ends of all the strings; `['Of', 'these', 'the', 'Murids', '(seekers', 'or', 'strugglers,)', 'are', 'formed']`including the one with the unbalanced parenthesis?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: why the negative mark without a reason? This is a valid question, if you can solve it, then do it.

Answer (score 2):

`(` is a special characters in regex. It marks the beginning of a capture group. Like so `)` marks the end of a capture group. Hence, neither `(seekers` nor `strugglers,)` form a valid regex (that you get after `split()` is invalid regex.

You should escape `(` and `)`:

`sent = "Of these the Murids \(seekers or strugglers,\) are formed"`

Now your code outputs:

```
[[(0, 2)], [(3, 8)], [(3, 6), (9, 12)], [(13, 19)], [(21, 29)],
 [(30, 32), (52, 54)], [], [(47, 50)], [(51, 57)]]
```

Another option would be to use [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#re.escape) that does seem to return a better result:

```
import re 

sent = "Of these the Murids (seekers or strugglers,) are formed"
stringlist = sent.split()

print([[(m.start(0), m.end(0)) for m in re.finditer(re.escape(s), sent)] for s in stringlist])
# [[(0, 2)], [(3, 8)], [(3, 6), (9, 12)], [(13, 19)], [(20, 28)],
#   [(29, 31), (50, 52)], [(32, 44)], [(45, 48)], [(49, 55)]]
```

Comment: many thanks for your response, I prefer the second solution as other problematic special characters would automatically be removed before initiating the find. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

()   []   $   ^   \   .   |   {}   are special characters for python regex. 
Try putting \ before each parenthesis and you get the result you want.

You output will be:

```
[[(0, 2)], [(3, 8)], [(3, 6), (9, 12)], [(13, 19)], 
[(21, 29)], [(30, 32), (52, 54)], [], [(47, 50)], [(51, 57)]]
```

Comment: I'm working with thousands of sentences and strings, how then do I go about putting forward / on every sentence when I don't even know which sentence contain a special character?